# How to logically index entire columns in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

Given a logical column vector (size n x 1) `v` and an array `a` (size m x n) how do I generate a new array consisting of all the columns in `a` where the numerical index of said column (1...n) is 1 at the corresponding location in `v`.

So for example if `v` was

```
1
0
0
1
```

and `a` was

```
1 4 7 10
2 5 8 11
3 6 9 12
```

the new array would be

```
1 10
2 11
3 12
```

because the first and fourth elements of `v` are 1 (true), so the new array should contain the first and fourth columns of `a`.

I have tried a bunch of things involving normal logical indexing and transpose but I can't get it to work. All help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the logical indexing to select the columns and select all rows. In the example below, I have explicitly cast `v` as a logical just in case it's *not* a logical matrix already.

```
new = a(:, logical(v))

   1    10
   2    11
   3    12
```

Comment: Wow, I tried something exactly like this except I switched the row and column arguments and so obviously it didn't work. Thank you very much, this is perfect.